SeleniumのEC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)について
Mac OS X Big Surを使用して、Pythonでプログラムを組んでいます。タイトルのメソッドを次のようにして使用しています。
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import schedule

run_time = "07:00"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

target_url = 'https://reserve.central.co.jp/reserve/schedule/10/13?filter_datetimes=20240515'

lesson_index = 5 # 0から9まで設定する可能性あり。

# リンクのXpath。Chromeの「検証」で調べた。
target_xpath = '//*[@id="__layout"]/div/div[1]/section/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[' + str(lesson_index) + ']'

def get_page():
    try:
        driver.get(target_url)

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

        x_path = target_xpath
        locator = (By.XPATH, x_path)

        print('スタートページ: ' + driver.current_url)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()
        print('クリック後のページ: ' + driver.current_url)

        space_locator = (By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@class,"d_studio") and contains(text(), "10")]')
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(space_locator))

    finally:
        driver.close()
        quit()

schedule.every().day.at(run_time).do(get_page)

# jobの実行監視、指定時刻になったらjob関数を実行
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    sleep(1)

実行後にプログラムを動かすとlocatorで選んだリンク先のページに切り替わるように記述したつもりです。
しかし、リンク先のページに切り替わる時もありますが、時々ページが切り替わらずに、
waitで設定した時間が経過してしまって、例外が発生することがあります。
ページが切り替わらない時のコンソールでの表示は、
スタートページ: https://reserve.central.co.jp/reserve/schedule/10/13?filter_datetimes=20240515

クリック後のページ: https://reserve.central.co.jp/reserve/schedule/10/13?filter_datetimes=20240515

となっています。
また、次のように変数を使うと「必ず」例外が発生します。
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
element.click()

質問は、

element_to_be_clickable()の使い方がおかしいのか？
どうしてwait.until()の返り値を変数で受けてclick()をしてもリンククリックがされないのか？

以上です。
ご回答または、参考資料のご教示をよろしくお願いいたします。

問題や現象の把握・調査のためには、要約したりして詳細な情報が失われた状況ではなく、行った事/手順や表示されたエラーメッセージ内容をそのまま質問記事に記述してください。それらの情報が重要で、書かれていれば直ぐに回答が得られる場合があります。そして使ったURLやXPathも差し支えなければ伏せずにそのまま、問題が有るなら回答しようとする人が試せるような内容に書き変えて提示してみてください。ソースコードも断片ではなくそのまま試せるようなものを用意した方が良いでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考にしてみてください。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方, XY問題

コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘、ごもっともです。それに従い、投稿記事の内容を修正しました。ところで、私が最初に記述した、記事の最初の文を削除されましたね？他の人が他人の記事を添削できることは知りませんでした！記事の内容を書き換える場合は、その理由をお伝えください。よろしくお願いいたします。

最初の時々発生する例外はともかく(それでも記録に取って質問記事に記述した方が良いですが)、2つ目の変数を使うと必ず発生する例外のエラーメッセージ内容は何時でも見られるので質問記事に記述できるのではありませんか？ それから変数を使う記述の方は、最初の行でwait.until()の戻り値を更に.click()した結果をelementに代入していますが、.click()メソッドの戻り値はNoneのはず(click() → None)なのでNoneであるelementに対して.click()を呼び出しても例外になるのは当然なのでは？

コメントありがとうございます。例外でエラーが出たら、そのエラーメッセージを質問内容に追加します。それと、２つ目の質問についてのステートメント文を修正しました。wait.until()の戻り値（オブジェクト）はwebelement型と記憶していますが、質問のように記述するとエラーとなってダンプリストがズラッと表示されます。

2つ目の件は何か動作環境か版数に依存する問題かもしれませんね。Windows11, Python3.11.9, selenium4.20.0でscheduleは使わずに直接get_page()を呼び出し、修正した2つ目の方法でclick()するように変更して実行した場合、問題無く動作しました。初期の質問で記述されていたwait.until(...).click()の結果を更にclick()する場合は例外になることも確認しています。
